# Custom UI Controls in Objective C Look Like Standard Controls

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I am not an expert in Objective C and have never submitted an iPhone app. I just want to check if this idea would pass Apple for App Store. Basically, I want to create custom UI controls that look like standard controls such as button, list, etc... The reason is based on business decision and these custom controls would have different behavior. No way to go around that. If I do so, would this be a red flag from Apple for copying their UI controls or not using their standard ones?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Human Interface guide (HIG) for iOS apps provides a good overview of what is expected interns of functionality and interface design.

Custom control interface are allowed just as long as they don't meet a users expectations as to what the result of using the control is.  You can copy apples controls and UIs but just don't change the expected behaviour of said controls.

Comment: I read that but it's hard to imagine since there is no example. So here is an example: if there is a list and in the bottom of the list, I have a list item which is my custom control. Other list items would go to a screen in the app. But the custom list item control will go to a website. Would this example violate the HIG?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that scenario. Its like having a show more button that opens a website instead of loading items internally from within the app.  As long as the button is obvious as to what the intention is.  If the bottom control had something like "open site" or even had a website/browser icon, I believe it should be fine.  I've only heard of apps being rejected for clearly not doing what they said they would do.